# How to init collectionViewCell with image without Storyboard or nib?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to init collection view Cell with image without Storyboard or nib ?

I'm building ImagePicker and want to do it without storyboards

so the working code with storyboard is like that, but how to do it programmatically ?

```
class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var image: UIImage? {
        get { return imageView.image }
        set { imageView.image = newValue }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }

}
```

My changed code without IBOutlet:

```
class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    public var asset: PHAsset!
    public var cellTappedAction: ((PHAsset) -> ()) = { _ in }

    var image: UIImage? {
        get { return imageView.image }
        set { imageView.image = newValue }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      self.imageView = UIImageView()
      super.init(frame: frame)
        self.imageView.image = self.image
        self.imageView.frame = self.frame
        self.addSubview(self.imageView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
//        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
self.collectionView?.register(PhotosCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

So the first picture without IBOutlet and the second one with it

[image: Non storyboard cell]
[image: storyboard cell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your class in `viewDidLoad()`

```
collectionView.register(PhotosCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "photosCell")
```

Dequeue your cell in `cellForItem` and configure cell's subviews

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photosCell", for: indexPath)
// configure cell subviews
```

Remember to init your subview in `PhotosCollectionViewCell` as you won't be using IBOulets

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    imageView.frame = contentView.bounds
    self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: did all of that, it compiles, but I got empty ImageViews in my collection View, updated my answer

Comment: you need to specify a frame and set `image` property before you see anything, also don't forget `self.addSubview(imageView)`

Comment: I've updated my code and answer, can you take a look ?

Comment: looks great to me :)

Comment: the storyboard variant have no gray area at all :(

Comment: I'm thinking that something related to addSubview on init()

Comment: `(collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
(collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.minimumLineSpacing = 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145311/discussion-between-joze-ws-and--).

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to initialize your cell class with a certain image you should be able to do so by overriding the init method

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //set initial image here
}
```